# Adding wallpapers in GNOME Shell

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell, wallpaper

When executing `Activities → Settings → Background`, you can find three background tabs:

- [Wallpapers]
- [Pictures]
- [Colors]

In [Wallpapers] you can find backgrounds under `/usr/share/backgrounds/`, but which have been previously added to an XML configuration file in `/usr/share/gnome-background-properties/`. If you put new backgrounds in `/usr/share/backgrounds/`, but you don't add them to an XML file, they won't be displayed.

On the other hand, in [Pictures] you can find backgrounds under `~/Pictures/` and any new addition will automatically be detected and displayed by the application (this folder is "reloaded" or "refreshed" every time).

Is there any way I could set the [Wallpapers] tab to automatically find new pictures under `/usr/share/backgrounds/` as well?

If not, is there a way I could change the configuration, so that, when clicking on the [Pictures] tab, it will look under `/whatever/i/want/` instead of `~/Pictures/`?

I know I could just edit the XML configuration file (myself, with a script, or even with existing GUIs), but I am not looking for that. I just feel curious about the customization level of GNOME Shell.

I am using Fedora 20 with GNOME Shell 3.10.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is there any way I could set the [Wallpapers] tab to automatically
>   find new pictures under /usr/share/backgrounds/ as well?

There's no such option. The [Wallpapers] tab shows the default choice of wallpapers (which may vary depending on distros/admins) available to all users. Distros/admins may choose to alter the content of `/usr/share/backgrounds/` (along with the corresponding entries in the `.xml` file). I don't think it was meant to be customized by regular users.

> is there a way I could change the configuration, so that, when
>   clicking on the [Pictures] tab, it will look under /whatever/i/want/
>   instead of ~/Pictures/?

Yes, the [Pictures] tab is, to some extent, customizable. `Pictures` is one of the [XDG user directories](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xdg_user_directories) and is defined in `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs`. Change the default value `XDG_PICTURES_DIR="$HOME/Pictures"` to  `XDG_PICTURES_DIR="/whatever/i/want"`, restart the shell and next time you click on the [Pictures] tab in the [Background] settings, it'll look under `/whatever/i/want`.
The downside is that some other applications that use `XDG_PICTURES_DIR` will also default to `/whatever/i/want` instead of `~/Pictures`.

Comment: Is it possible to create a new directory (or symlink) at `~/.local/share/backgrounds`? Will that be merged with `/usr/share/backgrounds`?

Comment: @nikeee - afaik the answer is NO to both questions.

Answer (score 7):

`/usr/share/gnome-background-properties/desktop-backgrounds-default.xml` holds the settings for the wallpapers; while there doesn't seem to be any command to rescan that XML file (one still can add further XML files into there, which keep an up-to-date index of some other directory).

however, one can define individual filenames:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri 'file:///whatever/i/want/background.jpg'
```

and one can access other parameters like that, as well:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-options 'centered'
```

when scripting wallpaper-changes, one has to set `draw-background` before and after:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background draw-background false
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri file:///whatever/i/want/background.jpg
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background draw-background true
```

there's also the `gnome-tweak-tool` which provides a GUI to these `gconf` settings.

@see [Bug 682126 - Show the user's most recent photos](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=682126).